# customvalidator servervalidate parameters description

Tags: asp.net, customvalidator

The ServerValidate event of CustomValidator has 2 parameters: source and args.

What each of them point out to?  Any description of them please.

Thank you

Comment: I think these kind of simple thing can be Google easily

Comment: I did, but there was no complete description like Mehrdad's. Any way thanks for your attention on putting the first answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like all "`EventHandler`"-style events, `source` will refer to the object that raised the event (in this case the `CustomValidator` instance) and `args` will refer to event data associated to this specific event.

For [`ServerValidate` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.servervalidate.aspx), the `args` parameter is of type [`ServerValidateEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.servervalidateeventargs.aspx). It has two important properties:

- [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.servervalidateeventargs.value.aspx): returns the value of the input control you're validating (e.g. text in the textbox.)
- [`IsValid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.servervalidateeventargs.isvalid.aspx): you set this property to `true` if the validation is successful and `false` if it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Argument **source** is reference of validator control and args represent event specific data.

```
protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Value != "OK")
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
}
```